# String sentence consistency when sent over sockets

Tags: java, c#, networking, sockets

I am learning socket programming. I have a Java application as my server, and C# for the client. Just sending string lines from one to another. Below I have code snippets showing how I am currently doing it.

Anyway, being new to this, there are two points that are still bugging me:

If you send a very large string, it is possible that one fragment arrives, and then the other fragment. Of course this makes sense, specially in slow connections like mine. My doubts are:

- Suppose that my very large string is sent, and it will arrive in two halves. I suppose it is plausible for the second half to arrive before the first one - for whatever network reason. If this is the case, how is one supposed to handle this?
- So my very large string is sent and chunks of varying sizes arrive one after the other - what is the right way to determine that all these chunks belong to the same string line? In other words, if I send `"I like cats"` and the target receives `"I like"` and `"cats"`, how can it deduce that those two things are meant to be part of the same sentence, rather than two different sentences? I *guess* that this is entirely up to my own protocols: perhaps I can send over tags like `<start>` and `<finish>` as part of my sentence - this way the receiver knows that whatever lies between thew two tags is one sentence... assuming that the chunks arrive in the intended order (which depends on my question above).

---

### Receiving a string

**JAVA**

```
    while (true) {
        if (socket.getInputStream().available() != 0) {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));  
            System.out.println("Got message: " + input.readLine());
        }
    }
```

**C#**

```
    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
    System.Text.StringBuilder message = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    do{
        numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        message.AppendFormat("{0}", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
    }
    while(stream.DataAvailable);
```

---

### Sending a string

**JAVA**

```
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("HELLO");
```

**C#**

```
    string msg = "HELLO";
    byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    stream.Write(messageBytes,0,messageBytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you use streams then the underlying implementation will be using [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) which guarantees that packets arrive in order aka out of order delivery is *not your problem*™. If you use [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) (datagrams) you will have to deal with out of order and missing packets yourself though they won't be split up.

And most protocols should have a way of differentiating subsequent (logical) packets; for example by prefixing the length of the packet or by delimiting (post fix a special sequence).

Comment: Thanks. Does TCP also handle missing packets then?

Comment: @Omega yep it will resend a few times as needed until it just gives up and assumes the connection is gone.

Comment: When it 'gives up', I suppose it will throw an exception?